Exclude country usually preceded by a word
I would like the filter:
"name" like '%County%
to exclude fields with the word County (usually preceded by a word or two).
It currently does the opposite.

To exclude all fields that contain the word "County", you should use the NOT LIKE operator instead of LIKE.
Any words before and after:
SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE name NOT LIKE '%County%';

Words before only:
SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE name NOT LIKE '%County';


Thank you.  Obviously I didn't know that command exists.  I'm 100% self taught so sometimes I get lost.  Again, thanks.
